# UserDefaults observer stopped working after not hardtyping the parameter

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, observers

My UserDefault observer used to work fine until I replaced my forKeyPath parameter to a string Struct instead of hardtyping it.

How it used to be when it was working:

```
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "packagename.fontSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

How it is now (not working anymore)

```
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: UserSavedSettings.FontSize, options: .new, context: nil)
```

After the parameter change the function:

```
observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

is not called anymore...

Here is my UserSavedSettings.FontSize declaration

```
struct UserSavedSettings {
    static let FontSize = "packagename.fontSize"
    static let FontType = "packagename.fontType"
    static let Theme = "packagename.theme"
}
```

Any ideas how can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the rest of the code is ok, and the value of `packagename.fontSize` is actually changed? Have you double-checked by using the string literal as key again and re-run your test? Usually when this kind of symptom happens to me it's because of some other, seemingly unrelated, issue...

Comment: The UserDefaults values do get changed as the changes appear on another ViewController which does not need the observer. The code was exactly the same and working (with the observer), until I changed the addObserver parameter to my struct.

Comment: Note that a dot in the context of a `keyPath` has a special function (essentially chains `valueForKey` for each dot-separated component of the string). Having said that, it doesn't explain why your code works for a string literal and not for a referenced string with the same value... Is it possible to share the code that sets the values to defaults?

Comment: When I was hardtyping my valueForKey it did not have dots. So it just happened for me to use dots when I replaced it with the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that **when I remove the dots** on my UserSavedSettings strings it works fine.

```
struct UserSavedSettings {
    static let FontSize = "packagename_fontSize" // replaced . with _
    static let FontType = "packagename_fontType"
    static let Theme = "packagename_theme"
}
```

Something must be going wrong with UserDefaults when the string contains dots.